# Power Automate Create a Channel in Microsft Teams and make visible to all Team Members

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have created a Flow in Power Automate to create a new team channel when a new item is added to a SharePoint list. Each item/channel represents a project with various metadata assigned for each item.

The flow is working perfectly but when the channel is created it is not visible to the people within the Team and they must manually make it visible and update their channel notification settings.

When manually creating a channel in Teams there is an option to make visible for everyone, I wondered is this exposed in an API somewhere but not as part of the connector?

My Question:
Is there a way when the channel is created via Power Automate to make the channel visible to everyone in the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this can be done only from Teams client and it is not exposed to outside APIs.

Comment: that's a shame. Thanks for your response.